# lodash - object transformation

Tags: javascript, lodash

Data Source

```
var data = {
  "2017-08-09": [
    {
      "time": "09:00",
      "available": true
    },
    {
      "time": "13:00",
      "available": true
    },
    {
      "time": "13:30",
      "available": true
    },
    ]
}
```

Desired Transformation

```
newData = [  "2017-08-09": ['09:00','13:00','13:30'] ]
```

I have tried the following:

```
function recursiveFunction(collection){
            var newData = [];

    _.forOwn(collection, function(value, key){ 

        newData.push( {key});
        value.map( item => {
                if (item.available === true)  newData.key = item.time
        })
    }); 
    console.log(newData)
};
```

But not quite there :/

http://jsfiddle.net/oa6nbgpy/

Comment: Your fiddle is quite different from the code in the question, did you paste the wrong link?

Comment: whoops! I guess I did, just update it :) thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With vanilla JS, use [Object#keys](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) to get an array of keys, and convert them to objects using [Array#map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map), [Array#filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) and [computed property names](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#Computed_property_names):

```js
var data = {"2017-08-09":[{"time":"09:00","available":true},{"time":"09:30","available":false},{"time":"11:30","available":true}],"2017-08-10":[{"time":"10:00","available":true},{"time":"10:30","available":false}]};

var result = Object.keys(data).map(function(key) {
  return {
    [key]: data[key]
    .filter(function(o) {
      return o.available;
    })
    .map(function(o) {
      return o.time;
    })
  };
});

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Thanks, how can I add the logic to handle `"available": false` ? so I could only list times when `"available": true`

Comment: Use Array#filter before the mapping the times. See updated example.

Answer (score 2):

Map across the values using [**mapValues**](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#mapValues), [**filter**](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#filter) only the `available` times and pluck the time using [**map**](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#map):

```
var newData = _.mapValues(data, times => _.map(_.filter(times, 'available'), 'time'));
```